# Pass post ID from archive template to functions file

Tags: functions, loop, variables

I have an archive template where I am displaying a "featured post" at the top of the page. I am building my post loop for the rest of the page in the functions.php file. What I would like to do is get the post ID of the featured post from `archive.php` and then be able to access it in my `functions.php` file so that I can exclude it in my post args. The reason I am using this approach is that there are multiple posts tagged with featured and I only want to exclude the one that is being displayed from the loop that's lower on the page.

I tried storing it as a session variable by placing the following code in my `archive.php` file within the loop:

```
<?php $_SESSION['featuedID'] = get_the_ID(); ?>
```

And then I tried echoing it in my `functions.php` file with the following code:

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['featuredID']; ?>
```

But it does not seem to work. Is it possible to pass the ID from `archive.php` to `functions.php`?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to pass the variable using [update_option()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option). In my `archive.php` I have the following code in my loop:

```
<?php update_option('featuredID', get_the_ID()); ?>
```

And then in my `functions.php` file I am using the following code to get that ID:

```
$featuredPostID = get_option('featuredID');
```